# How to set a listener inside initState() in Flutter

Tags: flutter, bloc, cubit, flutter-cubit

So I want to write a BlocListener inside initState(), which functions to provide logic on **whether a code should be executed or not based on the current state**, like this:

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  BlocListener<InternetCubit, InternetState>(
    listener: (context, stateInt) {
      if (stateInt is InternetConnectedState) {
        print('connected');
      } else if (stateInt is InternetNotConnectedState) {
        print('not connected');
      }
    },
  );
}
```

I've called this function right at the start of the application launch, and this code can work wherever and whenever an event occurs (*in this case whether there is an internet connection or not*) like this:
`context.read<InternetCubit>().isInternetConnected();`

But the code does not run or is not called.
I've tried doing research, but I've only found 1 piece of information][1](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/issues/1948#issuecomment-731417231) that says:

> [BlocListener only receives updates after it is mounted in the widget](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/issues/1948#issuecomment-731417231)

Does using BlocListener only apply to Widgets, and not work in initState()?
Am I wrong in understanding the concept?

Thank you, please help..

Comment: initState is for sync initialization only.  you keep wanting an async value during a narrow window while initState is running, and won't be giving a chance for any other tasks to complete.  initState also must complete in time for the first build, which should be within the first 60th of a second or there'll be dropped frames. Consider the other solutions here that show you showing something until you know the state.

Comment: Ok, so the point is, to write async task that is more than 60 sec, isnt recommended, right? In my case, i want to call on HTTP when there is a connection or not on the first i open the page, so do you have any solution to my case?

Comment: Yes show something that says "waiting for connection" in the meanwhile.  Or play a video or something.

Comment: The point of my question is to give logic inside initState based on Cubit States, but from your comment.. Maybe should i re-route the logic or something? I dont get it

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You cannot call the bloc in that way. BlocListener is mainly used in the build method that is after mounting in the widget.

One way would be. Use BlocListener inside the build method of the widget.

```
BlocListener<SubjectBloc, SubjectState>(
            listener: (context, state) {
              // TODO: implement listener
            },
            child:  //add your child here.
```

Now I assume you want to do implement that in the initstate.

We can use the concept of streamsubscription.
In the stateful widget. Declare a Stream Subscription

```
 late StreamSubscription _cubitStateSubscription;
```

In the initstate() call the cubit and add listener to its stream

```
 InternetCubit internetCubit = context.read<InternetCubit>();
   _cubitStateSubscription = internetCubit.stream.listen((state) {
  //Access your state and implement logic
 
  });
```

In the dispose method do not forget to cancel the stream:

```
   _cubitStateSubscription.cancel();
```

Note: Both are the ways you can access your cubit. And there may be many but this would suffice.

Comment: Hmm, its not working.. Is it caused of where i start `InternetCubit internetCubit = context.read<InternetCubit>();`? I Wrote it in the SplashScreen, so it must have been called right? Or maybe caused of `StatefulWidget` or `StatelessWidget`? I dont know where to debug it..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `stream` property of `Cubit` like this:

```dart
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  final InternetCubit internetCubit = BlocProvider.of<InternetCubit>(context);

  internetCubit.stream.listen((InternetState state) {
    if (stateInt is InternetConnectedState) {
      print('connected');
    } else if (stateInt is InternetNotConnectedState) {
      print('not connected');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Hmm, its not working.. :( How can i debug it..? The `print` i wrote inside the logic doesnt come out

Answer (score 0):

You can use [BlocConsumer](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_bloc/latest/flutter_bloc/BlocConsumer-class.html) which provides `listener` . If it is about building ui based on state or state data `BlocBuilder`s state is fine.

```dart
BlocConsumer<SubjectBloc, SubjectState>(
    listener: (context, state) {
      // TODO: implement listener
    },
    builder: (context, state) {
      return Container();
    },
  )
```

Comment: Hmm, should i write that whole code inside `initState()`?
I tried to write BlocListener, but it doesnt works..

Comment: I mean you dont need to have it on initState, just inside build method.

Comment: Noo, please read my question.. I need to call on this method (`context.read<InternetCubit>().isInternetConnected();`) in `initState()`, so the function will work right after we open the page.. In my case, i call on HTTP call, inside that function, and refresh the page everytime i open it. BUT, i want it to call the HTTP **ONLY** when the internet is available..

Comment: Well you can control the flow calling API on `listener` checking state, and for build you can have `buildWhen`

Comment: Yeah, i read it on [flutter_bloc documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc#:~:text=called%20an%20optional-,buildWhen,-can%20be%20provided), but i don't know how to use it.. Can you update the answer so i can try it out, please?